# Python "stops" after distutils setup

Tags: python, sas

I'm trying to write a script which automatically imports Jared Hobbs' sas7bdat module for Python. It should run his setup.py file (I've copied the contents to my script), but I've found that when calling the setup function, the program ignores what comes afterwards, i.e. even if I add a print statement after the setup call, it's not executed. All the necessary files are in the correct folders, no errors/warnings are given. Python is still responsive, so "stops" might not be the correct description.

```
def runSetup():
    import sys
    from distutils.core import setup

    setup(name='sas7bdat',
          version='0.2.2',
          author='Jared Hobbs',
          author_email='jared@pyhacker.com',
          license='MIT',
          url='http://git.pyhacker.com/sas7bdat',
          description='A sas7bdat file reader for Python',
          py_modules=['sas7bdat'],
          scripts=['scripts/sas7bdat_to_csv'])

    print "done" #not executed!!!

def convertData(infile):
    sas7bdat_to_csv.py (None, infile)

runSetup()
convertData('C:\Python27\sasdata\pc.sas7bdat')
path = raw_input("Enter full path of SAS7BDAT dataset:")
```

Comment: You are trying to combine installation process with using the application. Your life will be much simpler, if you spit it, let user install the application completely and then, when all is setup, use it repeatedly.

Comment: btw: your code `convertData('C:\Python27\sasdata\pc.sas7bdat')` will not find the files as backslashes are escape characters. You shall turn the string into one of following variants: raws string: `r'C:\Python27\sasdata\pc.sas7bdat', double backslahes: `'C:\\Python27\\sasdata\\pc.sas7bdat'` and regarding path, even on Windows, you may mostly use also forward slashes `'C:/Python27/sasdata/pc.sas7bdat'`. I prefer using forward slashes on Windows, it works and makes the code more portable.

Comment: Thanks fixed. I tried running the setup separately, but then Python tells me 'sas7bdat_to_csv' is not defined.